# Ownership on USB drive correct but read/write permisisons denied

Tags: mount, permissions, usb-drive

I am really at a loss with this problem. I recently changed UID numbers of my users (username was kept) because I changed authentication to kerberos/ldap authentication.

This works all fine, I have changed all the home directory permission of the users ( 
including hidden files) but now I cannot read any usb disks that I connect. No problem to read the disks as root.

The permissions (with `sudo ls-l /media/usera/`) look like:

```
drwx------ 3 usera groupa 4096 Jan  1  1970 TRANSCEND
```

`usera` and `groupa` are correct and also has the correct number IDs.

Yet nautilus gives me:

> Could not open the file “/media/usera/TRANSCEND”.
>   You do not have the permissions necessary to open the file.

Needless to say, `ls -l /media/usera` gives me:

```
ls: cannot access /media/usera: Permission denied
```

This is happening for all users. I am thinking there must be a database for the disks (or users) somewhere that still links to the old uid numbers (an ACL somewhere?). But maybe I am completely on the wrong track.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I switched my system to use freeipa. I played around with the groups, but nothing worked.

I eventually discovered that I had a user directory in /media left over which had the wrong user id.

Running`getfacl /media/USERNAME` returned this:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/USER
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:1000:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

User id 1000 was the id of the original user and not the new freeipa user.
In the end I just removed the directory and let the system create a new one

```
sudo rmdir /media/USER
```